# Does HTML5 application support multi person vide conferencing?

Tags: html, html5-video

Is it possible to create an html5 application that supports videoconferencing between multiple people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is possible.
PFB the links to the demo and source code.

Demo: http://hackview.sdslabs.co.in
Source: http://github.com/sdslabs/hackview

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do , It works only in the chrome 19+ browsers and latest Firefox , here is the way of implementing WebRTC

[Video conferencing with HTML5](http://blog.gingertech.net/2012/06/04/video-conferencing-in-html5-webrtc-via-web-sockets/)